# How to drop inner shadow in NSTextField?

Tags: cocoa

I need to drop inner shadow for text in NSTextField, are there any solutions?

Comment: Thank you @rickster, I hadn't seen that MG post.

Answer (score 5):

The NSTextField is an NSView subclass, which has a shadow field, if you create a shadow object and assign it to this field, the view will automatically show a drop shadow when drawn

```
    NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2; //set how many pixels the shadow has
    shadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(2, -2); //the distance from the text the shadow is dropped
    shadow.shadowColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    self.textfield.shadow = shadow;
```

This works because all views when are drawn on drawRect use this shadow property by using [shadow set].

doing [shadow set] during a draw operation makes whatever is drawn after that to be replicated underneath

Comment: hi andrew, i added some explanations here, if you have further questions please let me know

Comment: Thank you; that seems to improve the answer quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for drop shadows in Swift 4.2.  Since drop shadows frequently (not always, but frequently!) fall down and to the right of the text, I've tweaked the sample offset values slightly in the Swift code, just to provide another example.

Think of the object the shadow is attached to as the origin (zero point) of the graph.  As you'd expect, positive X values cast the shadow to the right; negative values are to the left.  I'm not sure why in this instance ([perhaps something to do with the iOS vs. macOS quirk relating to the Y axis?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html)), but the Y axis is flipped -- positive Y values cast shadows below the object; negative values cast shadows above it.

So if you happen to be looking for a drop shadow that falls **below** and **to the right** of the object that's casting the shadow, you want **positive values for both the x and y values** of `NSMakeSize`.

**For Swift 4.2**

```
var shadow: NSShadow = NSShadow()
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2  // Amount of blur (in pixels) applied to the shadow.
shadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(4, 4) // the distance from the text the shadow is dropped (positive X = to the right; positive Y = below the text)
shadow.shadowColor = NSColor.black
self.textfield.shadow = shadow
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on MMAC's answer by putting it into an extension so that you can call it as a function off any textfield when you like.

```
extension NSTextField {
    
    func applyShadow() {
        let shadow: NSShadow = NSShadow()
        shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2
        shadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(4, 4)
        shadow.shadowColor = NSColor.black
        self.shadow = shadow
    }
}

self.textField.applyShadow()
```

I keep a collection of these extensions in a file that I can carry to different projects.